# Consume WCF library functions from browser

Tags: c#, wcf

I've a WCF library with some functions I use from Powershell and C# clients. Now I would like to use a couple of util functions directly from a browser but I'm not sure how to do.

First I added a `webHttpBinding` endpoint in the `Web.config` file, here is a slice

```
<services>
    <service name="MI_lib.MainService">
        <endpoint name="basic" address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MI_lib_http" contract="MI_lib.InterfaceMainService"></endpoint>
        <endpoint name="web" address="web" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MI_lib_web" contract="MI_lib.InterfaceMainService"></endpoint>
    </service>
</services>
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MI_lib_http" />
    </basicHttpBinding>
    <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MI_lib_web" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true">
            <security mode="None"></security>
        </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

A simple function define for test purposes is this

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet]
string GetData(int value);
```

Then if I connect to `http://localhost/MI_lib/MI_lib.MainService.svc/web` I get the following fault message

```
<Fault xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/envelope/none">
    <Code>
        <Value>Sender</Value>
        <Subcode>
            <Value xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">a:ActionNotSupported</Value>
        </Subcode>
    </Code>
    <Reason>
        <Text xml:lang="de-CH">The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver. Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).</Text>
    </Reason>
</Fault>
```

Any hint on what to check or which other information to provide?

Comment: You're going for a REST service since you're using the Webhttpbinding and you need to define aditional information to the webget attirbute like template uri so you can pass on your argument and call the method using getdata and not web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define a web endpoint, you need, in addition to using the `webHttpBinding`, to add a web http behavior to your endpoint, as shown below:

```
<services>
    <service name="MI_lib.MainService">
        <endpoint name="basic" address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MI_lib_http" contract="MI_lib.InterfaceMainService"></endpoint>
        <endpoint name="web"
                  address="web"
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="MI_lib_web" contract="MI_lib.InterfaceMainService"
                  behaviorConfiguration="MyWeb">
        </endpoint>
    </service>
</services>
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MI_lib_http" />
    </basicHttpBinding>
    <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MI_lib_web" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true">
            <security mode="None"></security>
        </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyWeb">
            <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Also, the URL that you need to use also includes the method name, so you'll need to connect to

```
http://localhost/MI_lib/MI_lib.MainService.svc/web/GetData?value=123
```